How to get metadata of files present in a zip in PySpark?
I have a .zip file present on an ADLS path which contains multiple files of different formats. I want to get metadata of the files like file name, modification time present in it without unzipping it. I have a code which works for smaller zip but runs into memory issues for large zip files leading to job failures. Is there a way to handle this within PySpark itself?
Here is the code which i am using:
def register_udf():
    def extract_file_metadata_from_zip(binary_content):
        metadata_list = []
        with io.BytesIO(binary_content) as bio:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(bio, "r") as zip_ref:
                for file_info in zip_ref.infolist():
                    file_name = file_info.filename
                    modification_time = datetime.datetime(*file_info.date_time)
                    metadata_list.append((file_name, modification_time))
        return metadata_list
    meta_schema = ArrayType(
        StructType(
            [
                StructField("file_name", StringType(), True),
                StructField("modification_time", TimestampType(), True),
            ]
        )
    )
    extract_metadata_udf = udf(extract_file_metadata_from_zip, meta_schema)
    return extract_metadata_udf
    
    
def get_last_modification_times(zip_file_path, expected_date, extract_metadata_udf):
    try:
        zip_file_df = (
            spark.read.format("binaryFile")
            .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.zip")
            .load(zip_file_path)
        )
        extracted_metadata_df = zip_file_df.withColumn(
            "file_metadata", extract_metadata_udf(col("content"))
        )
        exploded_metadata_df = extracted_metadata_df.select(
            explode("file_metadata").alias("metadata")
        )
        return exploded_metadata_df 
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred: ", str(e))


by using zipfile only
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col
    from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, TimestampType


metadata_schema = StructType([
 StructField("filename", StringType(), True),
 StructField("modification_time",TimestampType(), True)])

def extract_zip_metadata(zip_filepath):
   with zip file.ZipFile(zip_filepath,'r') as zip_ref:
       for zip_info in zip_ref.infolist():
           yield(zip_inof.filename, datetime.datetime(*zip_info.date_time).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc))

zip_files_df = spark.read.format("binaryFile")
            .option("path", "*.zip")
            .load(zip_file_path)
        )

metadata_df = (zip_files_df.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: extract_zip_metadata(row.zip_filepath)).toDF(schema = metadata_schema))

metadata.df.show()

try this

I cannot access the underlying rdd of dataframes. I have to work with dataframes only

I have posted below another approach only with dataframe @Warriorq

    def extract_zip_metadata_udf(zip_filepath):
        try:
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filepath, 'r') as zip_ref:
                return [(zip_info.filename, 
                         datetime.datetime(*zip_info.date_time).replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc))
                        for zip_info in zip_ref.infolist()]
        except Exception as e:
            return []
    
extract_zip_metadata_udf = udf(extract_zip_metadata_udf, ArrayType(metadata_schema))

    
    metadata_df = (zip_files_df
                   .withColumn("metadata", extract_zip_metadata_udf(col("zip_filepath")))
                   .select(col("zip_filepath"), explode(col("metadata")).alias("metadata"))
                   .select(col("zip_filepath"), col("metadata.*")))

metadata_df.show()

try this without rdd using only data frames

I ran this code with few changes but it did not work as I got no record in my metadata_df. So i tested the udf function separately with a path and the function is giving exception, no such file or directory. For context the path is an ADLS path
